# Media files not loading

Tags: uploads, media

[image: Settings/Media]

I'm doing local development with WP-Turkish and Settings/Media does not show media upload path, so I can not load media.

Answer (score 0):

WordPress 4.9.5 does not have the field to specify the upload path. You can do it by editing the `wp-config.php`:

```
define( 'UPLOADS', 'wp-content/media' ); // relative to ABSPATH
```

See [Moving uploads folder](https://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#Moving_uploads_folder).

Comment: that did not solve although I re-installed WP, can it be something with my Ubuntu ?

Comment: Check read/write/execute permissions when on Ubuntu. And enable error reporting (`WP_DEBUG`) to see what really happens.

Comment: Neither displays nor records error to error.log, all permission are set.

Comment: Any more suggestions please?

Comment: solved by making media permissions to 777.